# Windows 7, 64 bit, 16GB RAM, solid state hard drive starting to slow down

Tags: windows-7

My desktop, which is about 6 months old and fairly powerful, recently started to slow a little when application screens are turned on or off. What used to be almost instant now sometimes takes a second or two to open or disappear while shimmying or vibrating ever so slightly while opening or disappearing when turning off.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? Running Windows 7 home premium, service pack 1, 16 GB RAM, solid state hard , 64 bit.

Comment: This is like me asking you why *I* was late to work today, too many variables and it is not the right format to attempt to troubleshoot an entire system on SU.

Comment: @AthomSfere You were late because of all that shimmyiinf you were doing last night. :)

Comment: It's Windows...

Comment: post pictures of CrystalDiskInfo

Comment: How many free space left on your hard drive ? You must leave 20% free on SSD to get good performance.

Comment: Do you have an antivirus in your system ?

Answer (score 0):

A number of things could do this. Most of the time viruses and adware will put stress on your PC and use A LOT of your PCs processing power no matter how much RAM you have. It could be software you recently installed which is a memory hog(antivirus is one of them). did you ever make a restore point while it was running fast? I'd recommend going to that point just so we could eliminate any software causes. If it were a hardware issue, most of the times your PC would just not turn on and beep at you. unless of course the PC isn't picking up more than 1gb RAM for some reason.

Answer (score -2):

This problem may be due to the latest software installed. Check by uninstalling that software and also defragment your hard disk there may lots of fragmentation causing speed slow of your computer.

Also check the start-up using **msconfig** command in run and uncheck the unnecessary softwares at start-up that you are not using regularly.